# Determine the upper bound of a recurrence relation:$T(n)\le T(n-4)+T(n-10)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I'm working on an algorithms that results into the following recurrence relation:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
T(n)=1,\text{ for } n \le10\\
T(n)\le T(n-4)+T(n-10), \text{ for } n > 10
\end{array}
\right.$$
I try to expand it $k$-th times but it does not seem to make sense. Could any one help me out here?

Comment: [Wolfy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(n)%3Df(n-4)%2Bf(n-10)+,+f(1)%3D1) says no such relation exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the vector $\vec v_n=\left(T(n),T(n+1),\ldots,T(n+9)\right)^T,$ we can easily calculate $\vec v_1$, and construct the transfer matrix from $\vec v_n$ to $\vec v_{n+1}$. In other words,

$$\vec v_{n+1}=T\vec v_n=\ldots=T^n\vec v_1.$$

and here is how $T$ looks like:

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}A & I_9\\1 & B\end{bmatrix},$$

where $A$ is a zero $9\times 1$ matrix, $I_9$ is the $9\times 9$ identity matrix, and $$B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now it only requires some linear algebra to diagonalize $T$ and you can get the final answer.

Comment: I was told $T(n)$ grow exponentially, could you show me how that happened?

Comment: Your answer seems correct, but is there a more intuitive way to solve it?

Comment: I happens whenever the matrix T has eigenvalues with modulus greater than $1$. I didn't calculate the eigenvalues of $T$ but that should be easy to verify.

Comment: I think there are more *intuitive ways*, but this is the most *general* way.

Comment: I was wondering what's the field of mathematics dealing with such kind of questions. Is it the discrete mathematics?

Comment: @Mark No. Discrete mathematics is unrelated. I would rather say it's dynamical systems. Hint: If you are not satisfied with my answer, you can go to the bottom of the Wikipedia page [Recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) and check how they catergorize these things.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have $T(n-10)$ in you relation you will need to define the first 10 values $T(1), T(2), \ldots , T(10)$ otherwise you relation is not well defined.

Here[1], the graph will give you the first $30$ values once you have decided on your first $10$:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g(1)%3D1,+g(2)%3D1,g(3)%3D1,g(4)%3D1,g(5)%3D1,g(6)%3D1,g(7)%3D1,g(8)%3D1,g(9)%3D1,g(10)%3D1,g(n)%3Dg(n-4)%2Bg(n-10)

Comment: I have updated my question. I don't understand why such a relation does not exist.